# Loading Tensorflow model in Java

Tags: java, tensorflow

I'm trying to use my trained tensorflow model for object detection in Java.
I exported the model (trained with Python) with this script [export_inference_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py). This generated a frozen_inference_graph.pb file as well as a saved_model.pb file.

My understanding is that the best way to use this model in Java is to use to load the model via SavedModelBundle.load(). However, when I try this with the saved_model.pb file, I get the error `SavedModel not found in export directory:`. Is there a better way to load the model in Java for object detection?

Please let me know if you have any suggestions! I suspect that I'm doing something wrong in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SavedModel format encodes all model information in a directory, not a file. So you want to provide the directory containing the `saved_model.pb` file to `SavedModelBundle.load()`, and not the file itself.

You may find the [official sample](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/samples/languages/java/object_detection) to be instructive too.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The official sample link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library just for that. You can have a look if you want: [JavaTF](https://github.com/preafixed/Java-TF)

You can have a model directory with multiple saved_models, and manage them with ModelLoader. It is all described on the Readme.

Let me know if it helps:)