# load tensorflow model in java

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I have created, trained and saved a tensorflow model using python (yaml file)
Now I want to load and use it in java (eclipse).
haw can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I quote from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898262/5120235). *The SavedModel format encodes all model information in a directory, not a file. So you want to provide the directory containing the `saved_model.pb` file to SavedModelBundle.load(), and not the file itself.*  For more information go to the [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/samples/languages/java/object_detection) page.